# In SQL Alchemy, how do I include a field from a joined table in fields list?

Tags: sqlalchemy

Take these table definitions:

```
class Device(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'devices'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
    imei = Column(String(19))

class Position(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'positions'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
    device_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('devices.id'))
    latitude = Column(Float(8))
    longitude = Column(Float(8))
    other = Column(String(512))

    device = relationship('Device', foreign_keys = [device_id])
```

I can query for specific fields of a position like this:

```
>>> pos = session.query(Position.latitude, Position.longitude).first()
>>> pos
(-22.929775, -43.23409)
>>>
```

I can get long, lat and imei like this:

```
>>> pos = session.query(Position).first()
>>> pos.latitude, pos.longitude, pos.device.imei
(-22.929775, -43.23409, '123456789')
>>>
```

How can I query for latitude, longitude and device.imei (like in 1st example) without having to select all other data that comes with it (like in 2nd example)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've found the answer:

```
>>> session.query(Position.latitude, Position.longitude, Device.imei).join('device').first()
(-22.929775, -43.23409, '356891051241497')
>>>
```

The funny thing is that order matters. This one doesn't work:

```
>>> session.query(Device.imei, Position.latitude, Position.longitude).join('device').first()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/leandro/test/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/base.py", line 370, in _entity_descriptor
    return getattr(entity, key)
AttributeError: type object 'Device' has no attribute 'device'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/leandro/test/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 1724, in join
    from_joinpoint=from_joinpoint)
  File "<string>", line 2, in _join
  File "/Users/leandro/test/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/base.py", line 191, in generate
    fn(self, *args[1:], **kw)
  File "/Users/leandro/test/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 1798, in _join
    descriptor = _entity_descriptor(left_entity, onclause)
  File "/Users/leandro/test/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/base.py", line 374, in _entity_descriptor
    (description, key)
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Entity '<class 'test.Device'>' has no property 'device'
>>>
```

Comment: Indeed the order matters, because the first mapped class is assumed to be queried. If you simply had a `query(...)` clause it would work (and produce cartesian product), but the `join` does not as it tries to join `Device` with `Device`. One way to solve this is to join on `Position` (`session.query(Device.imei, ...).join('position')`) but you have do define backref for this (`device = relationship('Device', foreign_keys = [device_id], backref='position')`. Another way is to use [`select_from`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.select_from).